# How to resolve error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'FormOutOfTime'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, c++-cli

I have a project I'm working on in Visual Studio 2010 Express in C++/CLI (An explanation of CLI would also be appreciated) and I am stuck on the following error:

```
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'FormOutOfTime'
```

Here is my code:
Runner.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Runner.h"
#include "FormOutOfTime.h"
#include "FormParentalOverride.h"
//Variable Dclaration


Runner::Runner()
{
    // Do stuff if you need to

    this->Go();
}

Runner::~Runner()
{
    // Clear memory if you need to
}

void Runner::Go()
{
    System::Windows::Forms::Form^ formOutOfTime;//*************************Uncomment Me Later!
    formOutOfTime = gcnew FormOutOfTime();
    formOutOfTime->ShowDialog();
}
```

FormOutOfTime.h (there is nothing really in the cpp file for this one, I'm not sure what the difference between putting stuff in the header and cpp files)

```
#include "FormParentalOverride.h"
#pragma once

namespace PurpleHealth {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for FormOutOfTime
    /// </summary>
    public ref class FormOutOfTime : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        FormOutOfTime(void)
        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }


    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~FormOutOfTime()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }

    protected: 



    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btnOverride;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btnUploadData;

    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btnLogout;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  lblPurpleHealth;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  lblTimeLeft;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::OpenFileDialog^  openHeartRateFile;
    private: System::ComponentModel::IContainer^  components;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Form^ formParentalOverride;

    private:

        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>


#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^  resources = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(FormOutOfTime::typeid));
            this->btnOverride = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->btnUploadData = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->btnLogout = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->lblPurpleHealth = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->lblTimeLeft = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->openHeartRateFile = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::OpenFileDialog());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // btnOverride
            // 
            this->btnOverride->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::White;
            this->btnOverride->Location = System::Drawing::Point(692, 458);
            this->btnOverride->Name = L"btnOverride";
            this->btnOverride->Size = System::Drawing::Size(218, 66);
            this->btnOverride->TabIndex = 5;
            this->btnOverride->Text = L"Parental Override";
            this->btnOverride->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this->btnOverride->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &FormOutOfTime::btnOverride_Click);
            // 
            // btnUploadData
            // 
            this->btnUploadData->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::White;
            this->btnUploadData->Location = System::Drawing::Point(449, 458);
            this->btnUploadData->Name = L"btnUploadData";
            this->btnUploadData->Size = System::Drawing::Size(218, 66);
            this->btnUploadData->TabIndex = 6;
            this->btnUploadData->Text = L"Upload Data";
            this->btnUploadData->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this->btnUploadData->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &FormOutOfTime::btnAddTime_Click);
            // 
            // btnLogout
            // 
            this->btnLogout->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::White;
            this->btnLogout->Location = System::Drawing::Point(933, 458);
            this->btnLogout->Name = L"btnLogout";
            this->btnLogout->Size = System::Drawing::Size(218, 66);
            this->btnLogout->TabIndex = 7;
            this->btnLogout->Text = L"Logout";
            this->btnLogout->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this->btnLogout->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &FormOutOfTime::btnLogout_Click);
            // 
            // lblPurpleHealth
            // 
            this->lblPurpleHealth->AutoSize = true;
            this->lblPurpleHealth->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::White;
            this->lblPurpleHealth->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 20));
            this->lblPurpleHealth->Location = System::Drawing::Point(699, 377);
            this->lblPurpleHealth->Name = L"lblPurpleHealth";
            this->lblPurpleHealth->Size = System::Drawing::Size(203, 31);
            this->lblPurpleHealth->TabIndex = 8;
            this->lblPurpleHealth->Text = L"Balife Bracelets";
            // 
            // lblTimeLeft
            // 
            this->lblTimeLeft->AutoSize = true;
            this->lblTimeLeft->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::White;
            this->lblTimeLeft->Location = System::Drawing::Point(576, 427);
            this->lblTimeLeft->Name = L"lblTimeLeft";
            this->lblTimeLeft->Size = System::Drawing::Size(449, 13);
            this->lblTimeLeft->TabIndex = 9;
            this->lblTimeLeft->Text = L"You currently have no time left. Wait until tomorrow, or upload heart rate data t" 
                L"o get more time.";
            this->lblTimeLeft->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &FormOutOfTime::lblTimeLeft_Click);
            // 
            // openHeartRateFile
            // 
            this->openHeartRateFile->Title = L"Locate the file Containing Heart Rate Data";
            this->openHeartRateFile->FileOk += gcnew System::ComponentModel::CancelEventHandler(this, &FormOutOfTime::openFileDialog1_FileOk);
            // 
            // FormOutOfTime
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->BackgroundImage = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^  >(resources->GetObject(L"$this.BackgroundImage")));
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(1600, 900);
            this->Controls->Add(this->lblPurpleHealth);
            this->Controls->Add(this->lblTimeLeft);
            this->Controls->Add(this->btnLogout);
            this->Controls->Add(this->btnUploadData);
            this->Controls->Add(this->btnOverride);
            this->FormBorderStyle = System::Windows::Forms::FormBorderStyle::None;
            this->Name = L"FormOutOfTime";
            this->RightToLeftLayout = true;
            this->Text = L"FormOutOfTime";
            this->TopMost = true;
            this->WindowState = System::Windows::Forms::FormWindowState::Maximized;
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &FormOutOfTime::FormOutOfTime_Load);
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion

    private: System::Void openFileDialog1_FileOk(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::CancelEventArgs^  e) {
             }
    private: System::Void FormOutOfTime_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             }
    private: System::Void btnOverride_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 formParentalOverride = gcnew FormParentalOverride;
                 formParentalOverride->ShowDialog();
             }
    private: System::Void btnLogout_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 //ExitWindows(0, 0);
             }
    private: void btnAddTime_Click(System::Object ^ sender, System::EventArgs ^ e)
             {
                 openHeartRateFile->ShowDialog();
             }
    private: System::Void lblTimeLeft_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             }
};
}
```

Any help at all is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to define the namespace. Use it this way:

formOutOfTime = gcnew PurpleHealth::FormOutOfTime();